# How to get gmail contacts on my iphone?

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, contacts, gmail

Under the 'settings' -> 'mail contacts calendars' -> gmail

there is no option to sync the contacts

what's the workaround?

Answer (score 6):

1. Open settings
2. Tap Mail, Contacts, Calendars.
3. Tap Add Account,
4. Tap Other,
5. Tap Add CardDAV account.
6. Enter google.com for the server, and your login
   info.
7. Tap Done.

This will bring your Google contacts in, and it is
smart enough to show you a unified view of your Google contacts with
your Apple ones. I.E., if you have someone in both sets, they show
up as one contact, and you can see which pieces of data came from
each. It works very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Mac OS X, you can synchronize you Contacts on Mac with google (set it i Contacts settings). Then just synchronize with your iPhone via iTunes.